# How to align pagination links in the center

Tags: css

Here's the [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/poc7667/e5659eebff8bc0047025/raw/716d00279d957572af8c245ce3c5da2e636efda0/s.html)

The links are separated in multiple lines,

I want it at the same line and centered

[image]

### Expected result

[image]

## Current

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one here

```
ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```